# Deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I stumbled across a nice puzzle today. It had a picture and only mentioned that there is a missing grid from it. (I already tried a reverse search of the image)

[image]

I spend some time on it, and I think I found a solution. After posting my answer I left the office and headed home. When I arrived, I wanted to check if there was an update on the question only to find that it's gone.

I am very confused about why would someone do that. I understood that there is a privilege that allows users to see deleted question. Here is the [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25293/solve-the-puzzle-what-is-the-missing-grid) to the question.

I was really interested if my solution was the right one.

Comment: I checked out your answer, and I like it.  If you want to know if it was correct, you can always try contacting the author in chat.  Just use @adrien88 to flag him/her.  (Or maybe they'll see this comment and respond here!)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, thank you for the info regarding the author. I haven't saved his name. I don't think there is a point in reaching out to him/her, because Emrakul said that that the account was removed. Nevertheless, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the user opted to delete the question before your answer had gotten any upvotes.

The system permits this (though a single upvote stops it), but penalizes accounts pretty heavily for deleting answered questions. It's a moot point, though - the account was removed for unrelated reasons.